# Comparar fechas con momentjs en angularjs

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

Tengo el siguiente código en mi `controller`:

```
$scope.a="26-04-2016";    
$scope.c = moment($scope.a,"DD-MM-YYYY").format("DD-MM-YYYY");
$scope.b="20-10-2016";
$scope.d = moment($scope.b,"DD-MM-YYYY").format("DD-MM-YYYY");
if($scope.d <= $scope.c){
    alert($scope.d+' es menor a '+$scope.c)
}else{
    alert($scope.d+' es mayor a '+$scope.c)
}
```

Con ello comparo dos fechas entre el `20-10-2016` y el `26-04-2016`, a simple vista se sabe que el `20-10-2016` es mayor al `26-04-2016` pero al ejecutar este código me da como resultado que es menor.

¿Cuál es el problema?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No puedo probarlo pero creo que esto te funcionará

```
$scope.a="26-04-2016";    
$scope.c = moment($scope.a,"DD-MM-YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
$scope.b="20-10-2016";
$scope.d = moment($scope.b,"DD-MM-YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
if($scope.d <= $scope.c){
    alert($scope.d+' es menor a '+$scope.c)
}else{
    alert($scope.d+' es mayor a '+$scope.c)
}
```

Comment: Esto sigue comparando cadenas de caracteres, no fechas.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es este:

```
// Creas un String con la fecha
$scope.a="26-04-2016"; 

$scope.c = 
    // Creas un objeto moment a partir de ese String
    moment($scope.a,"DD-MM-YYYY")

    // Vuelves a convertir dicho objeto moment a String
    // que es exactamente igual a $scope.a
    .format("DD-MM-YYYY");

    // String --> moment --> String
```

Esto es redundante y es también la causa que estés comparando las fechas como cadenas de caracteres, no como objetos [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) de javascript  y cuando comparas cadenas estas te van a dar mayor o menor de acuerdo a un [algoritmo](http://es5.github.io/#x11.8.5) de comparación que sigue pasos diferentes(paso 4) a que si ambos operandos del algoritmo fueran fechas(paso 3).

```js
var $scope = {};

$scope.a = "26-04-2016";
$scope.b = "20-10-2016";

$scope.a1 = new Date('2016-04-26');
$scope.b1 = new Date('2016-10-20');

//$scope.a >= $scope.b => true
console.log('$scope.a >= $scope.b :', $scope.a >= $scope.b);
// "26" >= "20" => true
console.log('"26" >= "20" :', "26" >= "20");
//$scope.a1 >= $scope.b1 => false
console.log('$scope.a1 >= $scope.b1 :', $scope.a1 >= $scope.b1);
```

Así que las posibles soluciones pueden ser

1. No desechar el objeto `moment` original y usar este para hacer las comparaciones usando los métodos (recomendado)

   [`isSame`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/)(`===`)

   [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/)(`<`)

   [`isAfter`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/)(`>`)

   [`isSameOrBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/)(`<=`)

   [`isSameOrAfter`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/) (`>=`)

   Aquí hay un ejemplo

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('DateCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.a = "26-04-2016";
    $scope.c = moment($scope.a, "DD-MM-YYYY");
    $scope.b = "20-10-2016";
    $scope.d = moment($scope.b, "DD-MM-YYYY");

    if ($scope.d.isSameOrBefore($scope.c)) {
      alert($scope.b + ' es menor a ' + $scope.a)
    } else {
      alert($scope.b + ' es mayor a ' + $scope.a)
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DateCtrl">
  {{a}}
  <br>{{b}}
</div>
```

2. Convertir el `moment` a `Date` y comparar usando los métodos correspondientes

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('DateCtrl', function($scope) {
    // Tambien puedes descomponer las fechas y crear el objeto Date directamente
    $scope.a = "26-04-2016";
    $scope.c = moment($scope.a, "DD-MM-YYYY").toDate();
    $scope.b = "20-10-2016";
    $scope.d = moment($scope.b, "DD-MM-YYYY").toDate();

    if ($scope.d <= $scope.c) {
      alert($scope.b + ' es menor a ' + $scope.a)
    } else {
      alert($scope.b + ' es mayor a ' + $scope.a)
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DateCtrl">
  {{a}}
  <br>{{b}}
</div>
```

Por último te recomiendo que manipules tus fechas usando el formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Esto no es obligatorio pero es el estándar y esto te ahorrará tener que hacer muchas conversiones de formato de fechas en tus programas.

Answer (score 0):

También puedes compararlos como JSON, es decir :

```
if($scope.d.toJSON() <= $scope.d.toJSON())
```

Ayer mismo lo probé con AngularJS (Angular 1) y funcionó :)

Answer (score 0):

.format() convierte la fecha (el objeto moment) a una cadena de texto. Si usas el formato estándar, al ordenarse por año, mes, día no habría problema. Pero tu le estás indicando que el formato de salida sea día, mes año, por lo que al comparar las cadenas de texto las tratará como números, no como fechas, por lo que 26042016 es más grande que 20102016.

La solución es comparar los objetos moment directamente, o con las funciones de comparación de moment: isBefore() e isAfter(). Luego el formato se lo das en el momento de mostrar la variable.

```
$scope.a="26-04-2016";    
$scope.c = moment($scope.a,"DD-MM-YYYY");
$scope.b="20-10-2016";
$scope.d = moment($scope.b,"DD-MM-YYYY");
if($scope.d <= $scope.c){
    alert($scope.d.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ' es menor a  '+ $scope.c.format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
}else{
    alert($scope.d.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ' es mayor a ' + $scope.c.format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
}
```